# How can I realise the Microservices Pattern with React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I am wondering how I could use the Microservices pattern with my React application. I understand that this pattern 'splits' an application into many small applications as it were.

I thought that I could split my NodeJS REST API into different, separate processes, to which my React App connects. E.g. one only to get some user data, one API to handle authentication - would this make sense?

Apart from this, I was thinking how I could apply this pattern to React. I am splitting my React application into different Components, but would this component-split already count as a microservice? I would not think so since there are no separate running processes. How could I separate my React App into microservices and apply this pattern? Or is a wrong application of the microservices pattern?

I hope I am not misunderstanding the whole concept, I am just starting out and would really appreciate some guidance with this pattern & my React/electron/nodejs amibitions!

Comment: I've never heard the term Microservices used in a front-end context - it's always been referring to stuff on the server.

Comment: Oh so i do seem to misunderstand this a great deal then! So my NodeJS ideas make sense, but the idea to use this with React is total nonsense then I guess? That's probably why I'm finding it so difficult to make sense of it with React! :D

Comment: Yes, the way you describe the backend side of things makes perfect sense and would definitely be doable with React - the rest, I think you're overthinking :p